# module.find() is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have a pre-existing collection (which is on mongodb atlas), and i've connected it and cerate Modules and Schemas, and i can console log it , so far so good, but when i export the module to index.js i can't console log the data it say Model.find is not a fucntion.

PS.
i'm new to this

My code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uri = 'mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@wt-cluster-xd7ou.mongodb.net/test? 
retryWrites=true'
mongoose.connect(uri, {dbName: 'dbName'});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


var connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
connection.once('open', function () {
var menuSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    category: String,
    food_name: String,
    food_desc: String,
    food_price: String
});
var Menu = mongoose.model('Menu', menuSchema, 'menu');
Menu.find(function(err, menus){
    if(err) return console.err(err);
    console.log(menus);
})

module.exports = Menu;

});
```

this console log my data correctly

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Menu = require('../models/menu')
var assert = require('assert')


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Menu.find({}, function (err,menus) {
    assert.equal(err,null);
    res.send(menus);
});

});

module.exports = router;
```

here is where i'm trying to send the data to the HTML

Comment: The database connection event might be occurring later after the engine has executed.

Comment: @Samuel how can i solve it ?

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the results after trying ajbieber's answer?

Comment: @Samuel ReferenceError: Menu is not defined

Comment: Checkout my latest answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are defining and exporting your model inside the `connection.on()` function. Try defining those in a separate file and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create your model in a separate file.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
let connection = require('connnection.js')

var menuSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    category: String,
    food_name: String,
    food_desc: String,
    food_price: String
});
var Menu = mongoose.model('Menu', menuSchema, 'menu');
Menu.find(function(err, menus){
    if(err) return console.err(err);
    console.log(menus);
})

module.exports = Menu;
```

Change your db connection to

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uri = 'mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@wt-cluster-xd7ou.mongodb.net/test? 
retryWrites=true'
mongoose.connect(uri, {dbName: 'dbName'});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
connection.once('open', function(){
  console.log('Database ready.')
})
module.exports = connection
```

Save this as `connection.js` for `require` to work.

Test the route again.

Comment: i got this

`Database ready.
    events.js:54
    throw new errors.ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
    ^

    TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type 
    Function. Received type undefined
    at checkListener (events.js:54:11)
    at NativeConnection.once (events.js:290:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> ` and some more erorrs ..